# How to change multi user name by adb command?

Tags: android, adb

I want to change the user name with user id 10 by adb command.
The information is as follows.

```
adb shell pm list users
Users:
        UserInfo{0:Owner:c13} running
        UserInfo{10:User-01:410}
```

```
adb shell cat /data/system/users/10.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<user id="10" serialNumber="10" flags="1040" type="android.os.usertype.full.SECONDARY" created="1689765483753" lastLoggedIn="1689803120920" lastLoggedInFingerprint="Fri Dec 30 06:40:46 +04 2022" icon="/data/system/users/10/photo.png" profileBadge="0">
    <name>User-01</name>
    <restrictions />
    <device_policy_l`enter code here`ocal_restrictions />
    <ignorePrepareStorageErrors>false</ignorePrepareStorageErrors>
</user>
```

How to change the user name with user id 10 using adb command?

If I manually edit the file `/data/system/users/10.xml` and reboot, it will be applied.
But I want to know if there is a way to change it through adb command.